# "Inserting" Records into Fields from a Database Feed

Tags: tableau-api

So the background to this is I'm trying to create a survival curve based on a database feed from the directions [here](https://community.tableau.com/message/371880).

What I have so far is three calculated fields per below.  Patient ID is not a calculated field or necessary for the survival analysis, but I believe it could be useful for this question.  For reference, there are about 20,000 unique patients.

```
Patient ID | Time | Censor | Group

   Id1        3       0        1
   Id2        8       0        2
   Id3        1       1        1
   Id4        3       1        1
   Id5        11      0        1
   Id5        7       1        2
```

What I would like to do is insert two records (one for each group) such:

```
Patient ID | Time | Censor | Group | Link

              0                1
              0                2
   Id1        3       0        1     link
   Id2        8       0        2     link
   Id3        1       1        1     link
   Id4        3       1        1     link
   Id5        11      0        1     link
   Id5        7       1        2     link
```

I unsuccessfully tried to create an excel spreadsheet with these base attributes to union with the columns, however, an excel spreadsheet does not appear to be able to union with a database.

My next idea is to find 2 of the 20,000 patients where I can create a calculated field along these lines (not sure this is feasible in Tableau, please excuse my syntax):

```
IF [Patient ID] = Id3 THEN [TIME] = 0 AND [CENSOR] IS NULL
END
```

and then a [Link] calculated formula:

```
IF [Patient ID] = Id3 THEN NULL
ELSE "link"
END
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Would like to avoid inserting these records in the database.

Comment: Can you add the excel sheet as part of the data source with an outer join on it? Then you could create a calculated field to check if the excel table is null or not. Does that make sense?

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't appear you can yet join database fields to an excel file (yet).  I was able to blend the data in a worksheet... however, this appears to only allow these fields to be used in columns, rows, and filters.  Seems to be an issue combining these fields.

Comment: I think it might be better to write a formula that just designates two random patients who were censored to have [Time] = 0 and [Censor] is null until there is a fix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best / easiest option is to use an outer join to your excel workbook -- this is a new feature in Tableau version 10 (Cross database joins)

Then, once the dataset is combined, you can build business logic through a filter or calculated field based on the absence or presence of the Excel data.

http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/7/integrate-your-data-cross-database-joins-56724

[image]